# PHP Database Query foreign key data from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I try to build a simple blog system. database table like below.

**Posts**

```
+----+----------+-------------+
|id  | title    | content     |
+----+----------+-------------+
|1   | Tile     | Content     |
+----+----------+-------------+
|2   | Tile 2   | Content 2   |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

**Categories**

```
+--------+-------------+
|id      | category    |
+--------+-------------+
|1       | Category1   |
+--------+-------------+
|2       | Category2   |
+--------+-------------+
|3       | Category3   |
+--------+-------------+
```

**Post-Categories**

```
+--------+-------------+
|postID  | categoryID  |
+--------+-------------+
|1       | 1           |
+--------+-------------+
|1       | 2           |
+--------+-------------+
|1       | 3           |
+--------+-------------+
|2       | 2           |
+--------+-------------+
|2       | 3           |
+--------+-------------+
```

**I use this code**

```
<?php
    $posts = DB::get("SELECT * FROM `posts` LIMIT 5");
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo $post["title"];

        $category_ids = DB::get("SELECT categoryID FROM `post_categories` WHERE postID = " . $post["id"]);

        $ids = join(", ", $category_ids);

        $categorys = DB::get("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE id IN (" . $ids . ")");

        foreach ($categorys as $category) {
            echo '<a href="...">' . $category["category"] . '</a>';
        }

        echo $post["content"];
    }
?>
```

I know this is not a good way fetching categories.

Even It query same category over and over and over again.

Can anyone give me some guideline/resources/tutorials to learn PHP logics, OOP, Best Practices.
How may I handle this with OOP PHP.

And please also provide your ans for fetching categories.

I don't want to join the `post_categories` and `posts` table to fetching data because there are few more columns in there.

Also there may have multiple category in a single post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you don't want join  .. your code is more complex  and time expensive that a single joined  query

```
    SELECT * FROM `posts` LIMIT 5

    SELECT p.content, p.title, c.category  FROM `categories` c 
    INNER JOIN  `post_categories` pc on pc.id = c.id 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id, content, title FROM `posts` LIMIT 5
    ) p on p.id = c.id
```

Comment: you could find some useful suggestion https://phptherightway.com  and https://secure.php.net/language.oop5

Comment: Unknown column 'p.content' in 'field list'

Comment: answer  updated ... added  content and title in subquery  for post

Comment: Can you please see my question again ?

Comment: ```
 ------------------------
 content|title  |category
 ------------------------
 Post 1 |Post 1 |Cat 1
 ------------------------
 Post 1 |Post 1 |Cat 1
 ------------------------
 Post 2 |Post 2 |Cat 2
 ------------------------
```

post 1 have 2 category `cat 1` -  `cat 2` but it not show
I don't want to query title and content more then one time also the category as well

Comment: `
 ------------------------
 content|title  |category
 ------------------------
 Post 1 |Post 1 |Cat 1
 ------------------------
 Post 1 |Post 1 |Cat 1
 ------------------------
 Post 2 |Post 2 |Cat 2
 ------------------------
`

post 1 have 2 category `cat 1` -  `cat 2` but it not show
I don't want to query title and content more then one time also the category as well

Comment: @Samantha   . in your php code  you execute  11 query  (1 for the select from post and 5 + 5 for select from post_categories and categories)  this is obviously much time and resource consuming that one query  only  ..so is most convient  and also a best practice  .. use a single relation set of data and single database access that repeating over iteration the code  execution  .. Once you have your set  full of all data .. then you can show the values you need  one or more time just checking when the related  columns values  change or not ..  hope this suggestion is useful

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is a bit broad
Regarding your specific implementation, I would merge the categories queries, generate an output and echo it once

```
<?php
    $posts = DB::get("SELECT * FROM `posts` LIMIT 5");
$output = '';
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
     $categories = DB::get("SELECT c.* FROM `post_categories` pc INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = pc.category_id WHERE id = " . $post["id"]);

        $output .= $post["title"];

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $output .=  '<a href="...">' . $category["category"] . '</a>';
        }

        $output .=  $post["content"];
    }

echo $output;
?>
```

If you'd want some more order, I'd recommend to work with a [framework](https://mashable.com/2014/04/04/php-frameworks-build-applications/#rUQoGxBoiaqp), that will help you put things in order
and maybe read a about  [MVC](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/)